# How to bind an event on a section load Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

I would like to bind an event on shopify section load in admin I mean while working on the `Customize theme`.

For example working on slider in Shopify customizer. We might need some jQuery script that runs on the section load. This should be called every time while we change anything from customizer.

I tried the `shopify:section:load` event but did not get any success.

Comment: `shopify:section:load` fires each time you modify the content in the customize panel. Why is this not working for you?

Comment: I used `jQuery(document).on('shopify:section:load', sslider(event, this));` But it does not call function when I edit section from left menus. I have placed this code in `theme.liquid`

Comment: It's working for me: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-MF2PAWMwdzmVTuHORz_xTH8bnX5uGc/view This is the code in my `index.liquid` file: `jQuery(document).on('shopify:section:load', function(){ console.log('event fired - doc') })`

Comment: Thank you. I will try again and will share you the update.

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 2):

Put it in section javascript tag

```
{% javascript %}
function showAlert() {
  alert('listen to shopify theme editor re-render');
}

document.addEventListener("shopify:section:load", showAlert);
{% endjavascript %}
```